# RestAssured response validation using body and array as parameter

Tags: rest, assert, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to validate a REST response. Is it possible to use an array as parameter to containsonly?

Ex:

```
        String values[] = line.split(",");
        given().
            when().
            then().
                statusCode(200).
                body("value", containsOnly(values));
```

Also, can we use variables as parameters to other methods like HasItems, equalTo etc?
Ex: `body(HasItems(values))`

Comment: Please use proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You could use any appropriate matcher to check whole body or just part of it. Just take attention on a object type returned by pecified path - first argument of `body()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Response resp = RestAssured.given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.dpd.public.v1+json")
                .body(FixtureHelpers.fixture("request/request.json"))
                .post("/");
            resp
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("random.object", CoreMatchers.equalTo("value"));
```

This would work for request.json object like :

```
{"random":{"object": "value"}}
```